# How to detect if PDF has compressed xref table in Java?

Tags: java, pdf, itext

Is there an API available in [iText](http://itextpdf.com/) library to detect whether the PDF file has compressed xref table?

[PDFReader](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfReader.html) class of this library has some useful API with regards to xref, but none serve my purpose.

The requirement is to:

1. Check if the PDF has xref compressed table.
2. If 1 is true -> then "Uncompress" xref table.
3. Send the byte stream for further processing.
4. Once the processing completes "Compress" back the xref table to its original form

Any pointers in this regard would be appreciated.

**P.S.:** The implementation is not restricted to iText. Any other Java library which can achieve it can be used. Licencing (if required) is also not an issue.

Comment: As iText (and other PDF libraries, too) does these tasks under the hood itself, it should be possible to reuse the code for those tasks. I doubt, though, that you'll find the required method explicitly publicly available. Cross reference table management generally is an internal matter.

Comment: Do a web/SO search for 'Java PDF parser' - the word "parser" seems to make all the difference to finding this kind of thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, this is already supported in iText.
You need to create a `PdfReader` instance and then use `isNewXrefType()`.

To uncompress the XRef table of a PDF document, you can use this method:

```
public void uncompressXRef(String src, String dest)
    throws IOException, DocumentException {
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(dest));
    stamper.close();
    reader.close();
}
```

To recompress the XRef table, use this method:

```
public void recompressXRef(String src, String dest)
    throws IOException, DocumentException {
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(dest));
    stamper.getWriter().setFullCompression();
    stamper.close();
    reader.close();
}
```

Comment: Can you also provide some pointers for un-compressing and re-compressing xref table?

Comment: I've added two methods to my answer. You may want to combine them into one, adding a boolean parameter to indicate whether or not you want the XRef table of the resulting PDF to be compressed.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet might be to look at what else you want to do with the PDF and then use that library.

Comment: If it's open source, yes. The required functionality generally might be hidden away from the library user and you, therefore, might have to do some tricks requiring knowledge of internals.

Comment: You often find vendors of commercial products are happy to listen to your requests and add features.

Comment: There are quite a few companies with products which would contain this functionality under the hood. Or you can look to hack Icepdf, IText, JPedal or PdfBox.